# Everything in the render tab is covered in blue

Tags: rendering, light, color

I am trying to render an animation but everything is blue.  I've added lights but no dice.

[image]

Comment: Is it the environment hdri? Or the giant box everything seems to be in?

Comment: did you change the colour in World Properties?